# Regarding extracting of a value

Tags: java

I have got the solution to the problem, want to thank you all you guys since without your timely solutions and advise this was impossible to achieve and solve thanks a lot..!!

A solution to this problem have been achieved thanks a lot..!!

Comment: 59103-RRX12 is a String or a result from a subtraction of RRX12 from 59103?

Comment: You are not supposed to delete the question after you got your solution

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 59103 - Integer.parseInt("RRX12".substring(3,5));
```

Do like this it will first extract `String` 12 from it and then convert it to `int`

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = Integer.toString("59103-RRX12");
String[]arr= s.split(-);
int x= Integer.parseInt(arr[1].substring(3,5));
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not compile.

You would need to do...

```
   String num = "59103-RRX12";

    public int getSubStringInteger() {
        return Integer.parseInt(num.substring(num.length() - 2, num.length()));

    }
```